# cross domain iframe communication in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have website a and website b. b is present in iframe and it contains some javascript methods I want to overload those methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it's much better to do it with [Node.Js](http://nodejs.org).You install it to your server and you can do a lot of server thing and more with it

Answer (score 2):

[Windows postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.postmessage)

[Cross-domain communication the HTML5 way](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=109)

[An Introduction to Cross-Document Messaging in Internet Explorer 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511311%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Also check out http://easyxdm.net a javascript library for cross domain messaging.